# Using MV to rename large amount of files using a script

Tags: linux, bash-scripting, mv

I'm writing a bash-script to rename a large amount of files, using mv.
Original filename

File001.txt

New filename

file-new-001.doc

I can change the suffix but i do not know, how to insert the "-new-" Part.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If using `mv` is not a requirement, use rename:

```
rename 's/File(.*)\.txt/file-new-$1.doc/' *
```

This renames all files in the current directory. If you have files in subdirectories, use `find`:

```
find -type f -exec rename 's/File(.*)\.txt/file-new-$1.doc/' {} +
```

If `mv` is required, you can do this:

```
for i in *; do
    j=$(echo $i | sed -r 's/File(.*)\.txt/file-new-\1.doc/')
    mv $i $j
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using mv, by using the following loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.txt;
do
mv "$file" "${file%.txt}.doc"
done    

for file in file*.doc    
do    
mv -i "${file}" "${file/e/e-new-}"   
done
```